# UISplitview: access UITabBarController from appDelegate

Tags: swift, uitabbar, appdelegate

I need to access the UITabBarController, and the second of its subviews from the appDelegate.

[image: Storyboard with UISPlitViewCOntroller as root]

This is what I have tried in applicationDidEnterBackground:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
let tabController = leftNavController.tabBarController! as UITabBarController
let controllers : Array = tabController.viewControllers!
print("viewcontrollers \(controllers)")
```

The app crashes, complaining that tabController is nil. If i remove the UINavigation controller from storyboard, the UITabBarController is accessed easily with:

```
let tabController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UITabBarController
```

What is the correct way to access the childcontrollers of the UITabBarController, where a UISplitView is the root?

Comment: Why do you have a navigation controller followed by a tab bar controller? Could you explain how you would want the navigation of your app to be like?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't show the entire storyboard. The views connected to the tabbarcontroller are tableviews, which has segeus to a detailViewController (splitview detailviewcontroller). If I remove the UINavigationController, the detailviews will not any longer have the navigationbar with different buttons and back button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I had to use "childViewControllers" of the navigation controller like this:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
let tabController  = leftNavController.childViewControllers.first as! UITabBarController
let viewControllers : Array = tabController.viewControllers!
print("viewControllers \(viewControllers)")
```

Now I can easily access any of the viewControllers and run their methods from appDelegate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than embedding your tab bar controller in a navigation controller, you should embed the child view controllers in their own navigation controllers, like this:

```
Split View -> Tab Bar -> Navigation Controller #1 -> View Controller
                      -> Navigation Controller #2 -> View Controller
```

This is the correct way to use a tab bar in conjunction with a navigation controller.

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem. Well, I can access the subviews, but the detailviews will now appear without a "backbutton". Also they seem to appear modally (comes up from bottom), even I embed the tableviews in navigationcontrollers.